# Can't create a task from Twilio Studio

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

On Twilio Studio, I can get an SMS, reply with a canned response but I'm getting an error when I try to pass/create a task in flex:

SendToFlexWidget is not supported for REST API flow trigger

Even though I'm using the income message trigger. I'm getting this error even with the default message flow, any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have sms going through proxy and a flex messaging channel?

[Flex Messaging Configuration (via Twilio Console)](https://www.twilio.com/console/flex/messaging)

[Messaging in Twilio Flex](https://www.twilio.com/docs/flex/messaging-orchestration)

Comment: hey Alan, thanks for your reply, forgot to add, I can get a reply to my mobile number, but once I'm trying to sent to flex, I'm getting the error that it's not valid for REST API flow trigger

Comment: The above should have addressed it. Also, there are some required attributes in the Send to Flex Widget. The easiest way to get these is to copy the attributes out of the built-in Flex Messaging Studio Flow Send to Flex widget into yours (this is the flow that is created when you first set-up your Flex Project), to make sure you have these required attributes.

Answer (score 1):

I received a similar error message and it turned out the phone number was associated with the Flex project, but it was not "registered".   Registration is a separate step.  Not I said "Similar".  It was not the exact same issue.