# SendToFlexWidget is not supported for this channel/trigger combination

Tags: twilio, twilio-studio, twilio-flex

I'm trying to integrate incoming SMS messages to Flex, I have a trigger that uses Incoming Message transition to send the data to a Send To Flex Widget, I can see in the logs that its able to get the message, however when it tries to direct the message data to Flex, I see the following error in the logs.

Note that I'm using the Programmable Chat Channel in the Send To Flex Widget

```
LOG
Send interaction to Flex via TaskRouter

DETAIL
SendToFlexWidget is not supported for this channel/trigger combination
```

I'd appreciate any help, Thanks.

Comment: Possible Solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60498477/10739965

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't create a task from Twilio Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60496090/cant-create-a-task-from-twilio-studio)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same situation when I was first setting up a new Flex Project.  Turns out I had not registered the phone number with the project. From the console  Flex>Messaging